# Core Data two entitites of the same class

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'd like to have a `NSManagedObject` subclass `Food` representing food. Now I'd like to have two entities (or lists stored separately), i.e. `EatenFood` and `FoodInTheFridge` using core data. Both lists contain the same objects `Food` but i'd like to have them disjoint and kept separately(so `Food` can either be eaten of in the fridge).

How can I achieve this using core data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is an optionally persistent object graph, not a database. So the answer is: you do it exactly the same way you'd do it with objects. You have a base entity (Food) with two derived entities (EatenFood and FoodInTheFridge). When you fetch everything in Food, you get both EatenFood and FoodInTheFridge; when you query the specific entities you get only those.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question differently, here are some alternative ways to model this in case these are closer to what you wanted.

[image]